# How to print list of icons from Mac Finder?

Tags: mac, printing

I want to print what I see in the finder (using Mac OSX snow leopard). It's a big list of roughly 1,000 icons and I want to print all pages to get a good overview of the contents. The Finder's "View">"As icons" fit perfectly for what I want to print.

Question is how do I print this. I cannot just take a screenshot, because the content is way more than can fit to my screen.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This utility seems to be designed for the task

http://searchwaresolutions.com/default.html

There's a free 30 day trial. It will print icons, but you may have to fiddle with the layout options to get it to exactly mimic the finder on-screen layout, as it generates a document, rather than printing an exact screen dump.

Comment: I'd prefer a free, easy-to-use solution.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer after trying the PrintWindow app. Although it has an odd limitation for working with icons: you can only print in max 4 columns on the paper. 

(workaround: Print 4 pages on same paper will give you 1200 icons in 16 pages in stead of 64 pages)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the icons or just the list of items (folder and file names) as plain text? IF you just want the items as plain text you can either go to the command line and do an

ls -al

or you can select all the items in finder and paste the contents into a text editor like textmate or text edit. When you paste go Edit --> Paste and Match Style

This will paste a pure text copy of the Finder items.

Comment: I want the icons because it's a list of icons I want to print